# Efficient way to check if all textboxes are not empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to check if all the textboxes are filled before submitting the form, the way I'm doing this atm is like this:

```
If strGebruikersnaam <> String.Empty And strVoornaam <> String.Empty And strFamilienaam <> String.Empty And strEmail <> String.Empty And strBevestigEmail <> String.Empty And strWachtwoord <> String.Empty And strBevestigWachtwoord <> String.Empty And strAntispam <> String.Empty Then

    End If
```

I would like to know if there is an more efficient way to do the same thing.

Comment: Use `RequiredFieldValidators`.

Comment: If they all have the same class then perhaps consider using jQuery - Something like http://jsfiddle.net/TcFBY/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use multiple `RequiredFieldValidators` with a common `ValidationGroup`.

However, if you really want to go this way you could use `Linq`. Assuming all TextBoxes are in the same container control, for example a `Panel` called `FormPanel`:

```
Dim emptyTextBoxes = From txt In FormPanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                     Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text)
If Not emptyTextBoxes.Any() Then
    ' ...
End If
```